# Very basic question about ordinary differential equations.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, soft-question

> Solve $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{x}$$

$$\int \frac{dy}{dx} dx = \int \frac{1}{x} dx$$

$$y = \log(|x|) + C$$

Is this solution right? I don't think this solution is right. I think the following solution is right.

$$y = \begin{cases} \log(x) + C_1 &\text{if} \quad x \in (0, \infty)\\
\log(-x) + C_2 & \text{if} \quad x \in (-\infty, 0)\end{cases}$$

When we find a function which satisfies a differential equation, do we find a function whose domain is an interval?

Comment: Your second solution is (almost) right: it's $y=\log(-x)+C_2$ for $x<0$. Usually you look for solutions on the largest possible interval. Sometimes you have to consider several intervals, like here. When there is a discontinuity, you hav to consider the most general solution (it usually involves different expressions and constants on different intervals).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Thank you very much for your comment. By the way, I corrected my error. Thank you.

Comment: The solution is also correct on the form $$y=\ln|x|+C$$ or on the equivalent  form : $$y=\ln|c\,x|$$

Comment: @JJacquelin But it's not the most general solution, it's only a subset, and IMO, in an exam, it would likely be considered incorrect.

Comment: $y=\ln|c\,x|$ is exactly the same as $y = \begin{cases} \ln(x) + C_1 &\text{if} \quad x \in (0, \infty)\\
\ln(-x) + C_2 & \text{if} \quad x \in (-\infty, 0)\end{cases}$ . Of course the arbitrary constant $c$ is not necessarily the same in the two domains since $c$ depends on the boundary condition which can be specified in one domain or in the other. Thus $y=\ln|c\,x|$ is the complete solution exactly as the expression of solution on a piecewise form.